# How to rearrange a string's characters such that none of it's adjacent characters are the same, using Python

Tags: python

In my attempt to solve the above question, I've written the following code:

Logic: Create a frequency `dict` for each character in the string (`key`= character, `value`= frequency of the character). If any character's frequency is greater than `ceil(n/2)`, there is no solution. Else, print the most frequent character followed by reducing its frequency in the `dict`/

```
import math, operator
def rearrangeString(s):
    # Fill this in.
    n = len(s)
    freqDict = {}
    for i in s:
        if i not in freqDict.keys():
            freqDict[i] = 1
        else:
            freqDict[i] += 1

    for j in list(freqDict.values()):
        if j > math.ceil(n / 2):
            return None

    return maxArrange(freqDict)[:-4]

temp = ""

def maxArrange(inp):
    global temp
    n = len(inp)
    if list(inp.values()) != [0] * n:
        resCh = max(inp.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
        if resCh is not None and resCh != temp:
            inp[resCh] -= 1
            # Terminates with None
            temp = resCh
            return resCh + str(maxArrange(inp))

# Driver
print(rearrangeString("abbccc"))
# cbcabc
print(rearrangeString("abbcccc"))
```

In the first try, with input `abbccc`, it gives the right answer, i.e. `cbcabc`, but fails for the input `abbcccc`, returning `ccbcabc`, without handling it using the `temp` variable, else returning `cbcabc` and skipping `c` altogether when handled using `temp`

How should I modify the logic, or is there a better approach?

Comment: What will you do if the string is, for example, `aaaaa` with all the same character?

Comment: I've updated my code, It'll return `None`

Comment: `while re.search(r'(.)\1', s): s = ''.join(random.sample(s, k=len(s)))` – I'm sorry. 